# Two Errors in IE11 for React 15.5.4: "Invalid prop `children` supplied to `HashRouter`, expected a ReactNode. " and "unknown browser " in bundle.js

Tags: reactjs, webpack, internet-explorer-11

My React+Webpack App runs fine in Chrome and FF in dev mode, but not in IE11. I also used the babel-polyfill, but it didn't work.

There are two main problems as beblow:

1. Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` supplied to `HashRouter`, expected a ReactNode.
2. SCRIPT5022: unknown browser :(
   This problem pointed out that the error happende in bundle.js as follow:

   ```
   if (isChrome()) {
       regex = /^ +at.+\((.*):([0-9]+):([0-9]+)/;
       expected_fields = 4;
       // (skip first line containing exception message)
       skip_lines = 1;
   } else if (isFirefox()) {
       regex = /@(.*):([0-9]+):([0-9]+)/;
       expected_fields = 4;
       skip_lines = 0;
   } else {
       throw new Error("unknown browser :(");
   }
   ```

This code means when I use IE, the Error `unknow browser :(` will be thrown. But why there are these codes in my bundle.js? I don't know how to fix this kind of problems. I searched for long, but unfortunately didn't find the relevant answer.

Here are the project dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "antd": "^2.11.0",
    "babel-plugin-react-html-attrs": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babelify": "^7.3.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "fetch": "^1.1.0",
    "history": "^4.6.1",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "react-hot-loader": "^3.0.0-beta.7",
    "react-mixin": "^2.0.2",
    "react-responsive": "^1.3.0",
    "react-router": "^4.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-import": "^1.2.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.2",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.9",
    "webpack": "^2.6.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.5"
  },
```

Is there anyone having the same problems, any advice will be very appreciate it.

Comment: Ran into this today.  After further debugging I found the error was with missing polyfills.  For me it was fetch (had to install the isomorphic-fetch polyfill for it to work in IE11).  Good luck!

Comment: I'm having this problem too. Let me know if you found a solution